# Converting regular (Type-3) grammar to a deterministic finite state automaton

Tags: automata, formal-grammars, finite-automata

I would like to create a deterministic finite state automaton (DFA) M=(Q, Σ, δ, q0, F) that is accepting the language generated by the following regular grammar (RG) G=(N, Σ, P, S). In short I want to **convert RG to DFA**.

```
G = ({S,A,B},{a,b},P,S)
P = { 
S -> aA | bB,
A -> aS | a,
B -> bS | b
}
```

I have found these rules that convert RG to a finite automaton (which might not be deterministic if I think correctly).

```
1. δ(B, a) = C if B → aC ∈ P
2. δ(B, a) = K if B → a ∈ P
   K ∈ F
3. δ(K, *) = emptySet 
   i.e. q0 ∈ F, if S → ε ∈ P
   I dont understand rule 3
```

Now I am using these rules on G this way.

```
A -> aS
becomes
δ(A, a)=S
according to
1st rule

A -> aS
becomes
δ(A, a)=K
according to
2nd rule
```

Now I already have

```
δ(A, a)=S
δ(A, a)=K
```

which means the automaton is not deterministic because

```
δ(A, a)={S,K}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Rule 3 says that if you're in the final state $K$, then ignore any subsequent inputs (which is what's meant by the *). As to your last question, there's no guarantee that this construction from a regular grammar to a FA will yield a DFA. If it doesn't, then there's a well-known construction (found in every intro theory text of which I'm aware) that converts a NFA to an equivalent DFA.

Comment: @RickDecker I am not sure that is correct regarding rule 3. At least, it is not my interpretation.

Comment: @babou. Perhaps I should have said that from state $K$ there are no transitions available on any input. How's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rick Decker said, the algorithm doesnt guarantee that the conversion from G will yieald a DFA. Therefore I should convert to a NFA and than to the DFA. The howto is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_r9NwiKQbE).

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpret your rules (other than 1 and 2) is:

There is a state K, not corresponding to a non-terminal
of the grammar, such that K ∈ F.

Then rule 3 means that there is no transition from state K, so that
any further input when you are in state 3 results in rejection of the
input string. The star `*` means any input, and the empty set says
that any input will get you in no state, hence failure unless you have
no input left.

The initial state `q0` is `S`, and it belongs also to the set F of
final states iff  `S → ε ∈ P`

Thus the set F of final states contains either only the state K or the two
states S and K.

But as you remark, this gives you in general a NFA, a non-deterministic
finite automaton.

To transform it into DFA, you need to apply the so-called **powerset
construction**, that you will find in any textbook on finite automata, and in many other places, including [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction).