# How to draw a automaton with this description?

Tags: automata

I'm having trouble drawing an automata with this description
S ← abb|aab|aaabbb|aaaS|Sbbb.

I have tried drawing the abb and aab states but am having trouble making this into one automaton

Comment: maybe try it to forget about the description, and figure out the language $L$ generated by this grammar, then convert it to an automaton?  If the grammar was regular (it is almost at the right format), you could've used the method in [converting regular type-3 grammar to a deterministic finite state automaton](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40951/converting-regular-type-3-grammar-to-a-deterministic-finite-state-automaton)

Comment: See also our reference question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755

Comment: Hint: The language is $\{a^{3n}wb^{3m}\mid w\in\{aaabbb,abb,aab\},\;n,m\ge0\}$

Answer (score 1):

This is an option

[image]

an alternative method to solve this:

1. Convert to Right Linear Grammar G

   G = (N, T, P, S)

   N = no terminals

   T = terminals

   P = productions

   S = Initial symbol
2. Your new automaton A is

   A = (N U {qf}, T, d, S, {qf})

   qf is a new element

   d:

   Y belongs d(X, a) if X -> aY belongs to P

   qf belongs d(X, a) if X -> a belongs of P